# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:11.8.0

Tags: android

In my android app, I am getting following error. I have added required dependacies in the build.gradle file. below is my build.gradle file.

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:11.8.0
>   Install Repository and sync project
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>   Affected Modules: app

this is my gradle:
'''

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.0, 0.99.99]'

    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ext.sohbetuygulamasi"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true //important
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : '********',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation group: 'com.android.support', name: 'design', version: '28.0.0-alpha1'
    compile project(':layoutmanagercard')

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

'''